# Using perl, is there a way to open gzip files and read through the lines without fully decompressing?

Tags: perl, grep, gzip

I basically want to make a file handle for the gzip and use it to match strings like I would any other file.  I need to compare the lines from two gzip files but they're each 15 GB. I was using Archive::Extract and File::temp to read through them but my hard drive fills up.

Comment: `gzip -dc` will decompress to standard output.  `zcat` will do the same.  Unless these are tar files.  I know you asked about Perl, but this is an option.

Comment: There is also a gzip encoding layer: https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::gzip so you can open them like any other file.

Comment: Gotta be suspicious about PerlIO layers (as some load the entire file into memory). But at a glance, I don't think that's an issue with PerlIO::gzip.

Comment: I was using `gzip -c` and `zgrep` but it started to become really complicated (to me who doesn't know much about unix) when I thought about using `zgrep` for all possible combinations of strings from file 1 with file 2, plus I already have the script written in Perl that works with smaller files.

I was looking at PerlIO::gzip but the last comment below led me to believe that it was still going to decompress the whole file.


`use PerlIO::gzip;


  open FOO, "<:gzip", "file.gz" or die $!;


  print while <FOO>; # And it will be uncompressed...
`

Comment: This might be irrelevant but linux has zegrep too.  These are big files so if you can use efficient unix tools to grep and/or sort first, that helps, and if you wanted to egrep, zegrep is nifty for doing 2 things together.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe `gzip -dc` into filehandles like this:

```
 open(my $fh1, '-|', '/usr/bin/gzip -dc filename1.gz') or die $!;
 open(my $fh2, '-|', '/usr/bin/gzip -dc filename2.gz') or die $!;
```

It should buffer the output from gzip, and not use space on your disk.

`PerlIO::gzip` does not decompress the whole file, but uncompresses as it reads to your handle, so you can use this as well.